# Using scalacheck Generator correctly

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I'm having some difficulty in using scalacheck generators correctly. I want to test an arbitrary array with integer parameter in some range - the code is mostly following:

```
import org.scalacheck._

object BlockSpecs extends Properties("Block") {

  val arrayGen = Gen.containerOf[Array, Byte](0.toByte)
  val intGen = Gen.choose(1, 255)

  property("addPadding") = Prop.forAll(arrayGen, intGen) { (a, b) => 
    val padded = addPadding(a, b)
    (a.length != padded.length) && 
    (padded.length % b == 0)
  }
}
```

However, I get values for integer that *include* 0. When I change `Prop.forAll` into `Prop.forAllNoShrink` it works for some reason that is not clear to me.

Basically, I just want to do the following:

```
Prop.forAll { (a: Array[Byte], b: Int) => ... }
```

but with the `b` in given range. What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: You're saying `intGen` generates `0`? That sounds really weird. If you just do something simpler like `Gen.listOfN(10000, intGen).sample` do you get a list with `0` in it?

Comment: Ah, it seems that the generator is working properly after all, and only when failure occurs, scalacheck will try to 'shrink' the failure for 'minimal' failing test case, and it does not use the generator anymore in that phase: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scalacheck/eg406lA7LnU/kSKygUzyY7UJ